# Angular 4 app Azure App Service deployment

Tags: angular2-routing, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to deploy an Angular 4 app to the Azure App Service.

This is what I did.

- Run ng build --prod
- Copy the dist directory to the root folder.

Here is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

However, I got an error when I try to run the web application.

```
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please advise

Comment: Hey i have the same issue, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your web config might need some tweaking. Also make sure you are including it in the assets section of your package.json file.

Take a look at this guide:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2017/09/11/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/